# Prestashop - change all product ID at once

Tags: prestashop

Is there any chance to change all product IDs in `prestashop` at once?

I have a shop with approx 500 products and ID looks like `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, etc.  I need to increment all ID with some high number like `25000` or so the result will look like `25001`, `250002`, `25003`  ...

Answer (score 1):

There's no such built in functionality. You should write your own SQL request to update every tables containing `id_product` column.

It is not recommended to change old ids because it might break relation between your database tables and break your SEO with new url.

For new products you can change the `auto_increment` value of your `products` table. Then all futur products will start from this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can import items via CSV import, and put a checkbox import by ID from the file, then the goods will be the ID, which you specify. But new products you can add only through imports, because if you will create through the admin panel items will standard ID 1,2,3 ... and so on, even if you have a big name ID like 20001